# How to apply join on three tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables customer, address, and city and I want to find the city each customer is from. So I am using two joins but after the query execution I find out that no two customers have the same city according to my query can someone please help me is my query ok.
I am using `pagila` database.

```
select c.first_name , ct.city 
from customer c 
  join address a on c.address_id=a.address_id 
  join city ct on a.city_id=ct.city_id
```

[image]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results would also hlep.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using pgAdmin as my query editor

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right. You question's part - I find out that no two customers have the same city according to my query" could be true based on your data. We have no way of knowing without looking at sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what are you expecting?

```
select distinct c.first_name , ct.city from customer c 
join address a on c.address_id=a.address_id 
join city ct on a.city_id=ct.city_id
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your desired result?

Comment: Need the data, not relationship